# Json.NET Convert model to array and return to JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having trouble finding the `JObject` nested keys in order to convert the key values to an array. The code below seems to only get the parent keys instead of the entire object.

What I want: Convert any `ValuesToList` items in the `JObject` to `JArray` if they are not already an array irregardless of how nested the keys are. NOTE: Solution should work with entirely different Json models.

Purpose: Sometimes the Json returns as a model instead of an array which causes deserializing to a model to throw exceptions.

> result = {{ "errors": null, "content": { "officeId": 1, "daysClosed": [] } }}

```
// values in ValuesToList are "content" and "daysClosed"
var result = JObject.Parse(_responseString);

foreach (string item in ValuesToList.ToArray())
{
    // Check to see if toList value is contained in the JObject.
    if (result[item] != null)
    {
        // Check to see if the value is an array. If not, will convert to array/list Json.
        if (!(result[item] is JArray))
            result[item] = new JArray(result[item]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to find `daysClosed` in the `JObject` because it is a child. Thus, when `item = "daysClosed"` the `result[item]` will return `null`.

I was working on a way to use reflection to solve this problem but ran into issues where a new `JObject` would be appended to the current `JObject` and I am looking to replace the Keys values with an array if the keyvalue exists and is not already an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keys can occur at any depth in the `JObject`, you'll need to use [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) along with a [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to find them.  Something like this should work:

```
foreach (string item in ValuesToList.ToArray())
{
    // find all occurrences of the item in the JObject at any depth
    foreach (JToken match in result.SelectTokens("$.." + item))
    {
        // if the matching token is not an array, wrap it in an array
        if (match.Type != JTokenType.Array)
        {
            JProperty parent = (JProperty)match.Parent;
            parent.Value = new JArray(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EtDqNs

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try doing this:

```
var arrayProperties = result.DoSomething().OfType<JProperty>().Where(prop => prop.Value.Type == JArray);
```

Comment: This is great for finding the properties but I need to find the Key then convert the value of that key to an array and return it to the JObject as a whole. It appears that this only finds the properties. Also, Value.Type == JArray is not valid in the context. (JTokenType.Array)

Could you elaborate on how this solves the conversion? I assume you mean DoSomething() but if that is the case the answer still escapes me.

Comment: Take a look at this! :) by sure will [helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035964/identifying-an-array-for-a-property-value-json-net)

Comment: And if I understood bad your question, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764970/find-index-of-a-value-in-an-array) will helps you too